# How to display the line that match the user input?

Tags: java

I intend to let the user choose what they want to filter by choosing 1-5. If the user chooses 1, the program should ask them to enter the year they want to filter, after that, it should check the length of the input, if it is equal to 4 then it should check whether the text file contains a line that matches the input. But if the user enters 2019, which is equal to 4 digit, the record and the no such records will display at the same time.What if i only want the No such record to be disply only the year enter by the user have no record in the text file?

[textfile][1]

Comment: You forgot to ask a question (and to format your code to make it readable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the part of the code which causes the behavior you do not like:

```
if(line.contains(input))
{
    System.out.println(input);
    System.out.println(input);
}
```

Change it to

```
if(line.contains(input))
{
    System.out.println(line);
}
```